# Parse: correct use for pinned objects during extended non-networked conditions

Tags: ios, parse-platform, persistence, local-datastore

I'm writing an iOS app with Parse which has two tiers: free, and subscription. The free tier does not support cloud persistence of objects created, and the subscription tier does. That is, the user is welcome to download and use the app for free for as long as they'd like and create device-persistent objects during this time, which would later be uploaded if they choose to subscribe/log in.

I'm having trouble with the non-networked free tier.

To architect this tier, I'm using Parse's local datastore. Let's say a user creates a `UserData` `PFObject`:

```
let newUserData = PFObject.objectWithClassName("UserData")
newUserData["someUserDataKey"] = "abc"
newUserData.pinInBackground()
```

This part is fine. I'm able to query the local datastore `UserData` objects and create, say, a table view. The problem I run into is when the user later changes a value on one of these objects:

```
// aUserData is an instance of PFObject which has already 
// been pinned to the local datastore
aUserData["someUserDataKey"] = "xyz"
```

I do not then call any version of `aUserData.save()`, as I'm not persisting them in the Parse cloud. For the rest of time the app is open, all view controllers that display the modified `aUserData` will properly see `xyz` for the value of `someUserDataKey`, as expected.

However, if I quit the app from the multitasking view and reopen it, `aUserData` will revert back to `abc` for `someUserDataKey`. I did not expect this to happen; instead, I imagined that modifications to objects in the local datastore would persist. I also think it's strange that it does persist until an app relaunch, but not after.

I discovered a work around for the problem, which is to call `aUserData.pin()` after making any changes to the object. I'm not sure why this is required, and more generally what the expected behavior is when calling `pin()` a second time on an already pinned object.

What are the best practices for this kind of setup?

Comment: You're not using the framework in a way that is expected. Pinning is like local saving, but you aren't strictly expected to only want to save locally, you're expected to want to save to network, even if it doesn't happen immediately. You will likely have other issues in future if you use relationships. It would be better to use your own local data store and save to network when required explicitly from there...

Comment: Well, the intent is that once they log in with a subscription, the pinned objects they've created will all be uploaded to Parse's cloud. The benefit to me of using Parse this way is that I don't have to bifurcate my model implementation by free vs. sub.; also, I take advantage of Parse's automatic anon user -> signed up user migration of the PFObjects created in the free phase. So yeah, it'd be a bummer if I can't do this this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do upload all objects in all cases, just don't make the account available on other devices / allow user specified login details until its signed up.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to actually create a real user for the device. Generate UUIDs for the username and password and store them in the device keychain. When the user isn't signed up you always login with those details. When the user signs up you update the current user with the new details and delete the old details from the keychain.

Comment: Parse supports a built-in automatic anonymous user workflow, so I don't think the second bit is engineering that I need to do. I could upload everything for the free tier users, but I wanted to avoid that so as to not incur API request costs for those non-revenue generating people. If there is no official word on whether re-pinning objects is well-defined behavior, I guess I'd have to weigh whether I should upload free tier data and incur a monetary cost, or engineer a non-Parse model in my code for free tier people.